# What does `exit` keyword do in Python3 with Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, exit, keyword

I am currently using Python3 in Jupyter Notebook and I just ran into a keyword `exit`. What does this keyword do ?

```
with open("some_file.txt") as f:
    for lines in f:
        print(lines)
        exit
```

Comment: Undoing my dupe-close because apparently this behaves differently in Jupyter/IPython.

Comment: Is that `exit` something specific to jupyter?  Normally in python the code uses `sys.exit()`.   Whatever this does it will do it for every line read from the file.

Comment: `exit` is not a key-word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `exit` lines in your loop do nothing. Why they do nothing is a bit more complicated than the usual reason `exit` would do nothing in Python, though.

---

Normally, `exit` on a line by its own wouldn't exit Python. At most, in interactive mode, it would print a message telling you how to quit Python (message implemented in [`_sitebuiltins.Quitter.__repr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Lib/_sitebuiltins.py#L17)):

```
>>> exit
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
```

IPython does something different. Among the many extra systems IPython has for interactive convenience is a system to [autocall](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.autocall.html) instances of a certain type, `IPython.core.autocall.IPyAutocall`. (This is similar to but distinct from the [`%autocall`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-autocall) magic.)

In IPython, `exit` and `quit` are set to instances of [`IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.autocall.html#IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall), a subclass of `IPyAutocall`. IPython recognizes objects of this type, so when a line containing just `exit` or `quit` is executed, IPython actually exits.

```
In [1]: exit
[IPython dies here]
```

A Jupyter notebook's IPython kernel has `exit` and `quit` set to instances of the very closely related [`IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.autocall.html#IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall), which has some extra functionality to support a `keep_kernel` argument, but is otherwise the same.

This functionality only triggers when a line referring to the autocallable object is the entire content of the cell, though. Inside a loop, the autocall functionality doesn't trigger, so we're back to nothing happening.

In fact, even less happens than what would happen in normal interactive mode - in a normal, non-IPython interactive session, this loop would print the "Use exit()..." message on each iteration, due to differences in how IPython and the regular interactive mode handle expression auto-printing.

Comment: It also has an optional parameter to keep the kernel running - https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/48#issuecomment-299674959

Comment: @Kingsley which I assume Spyder is doing in my case, and I suspect Jupyter would invoke by default. I can't see much use for this other than a wipe of the namespace otherwise. If you actually shut the IPython kernel down then you can't do a whole lot

Comment: Actually, it might be a part of [IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.autocall.html#IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall) The behaviour and the parameter seems to support it.

Answer (score 4):

When `exit` (*sic*, with no parentheses) is used in iPython *in a loop or a branch of a conditional statement*, it is doing nothing because it is simply a reference to an instance of `IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall`:

```
for i in range(10): 
    exit 
print(i)
# 9

if i==9: 
   exit 
   print(exit)    
# <IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall object at 0x7f76ad78a4a8>
```

It does not restart the kernel:

```
print(i)
# 9
```

However, when used on the command line *alone*, it is *treated as a kind of magic* (though without a `%`) and terminates the kernel.

Comment: No, it really isn't _sic_. It _does_ do something in IPython

Comment: I can run it in the IPython console and it forces a reset in Spyder

Comment: No, it looks like this is right - the loop changes things in a way I didn't account for. I need to revise my answer a bit more.

Comment: @roganjosh Like it is doing _what_?

Comment: Resetting the whole kernel: https://ibb.co/80tgRXD . The black line is the division between two screenshots

Comment: @roganjosh Not in a loop or a branch (see the updated answer).

Comment: @roganjosh Pretty much so. Just like any other reference to an object or a function.

Comment: The system that causes `exit` to exit the kernel is similar to the magic system, but it's not the same system. `%exit` would be invalid, since there is no `%exit` line magic.

Comment: @user2357112 Agree, changed the note in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

On my simple test,
Cell 1
`a = 3`
Cell 2
`exit`
cell 3
`print(a)`

resulted in

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3f786850e387> in <module>
----> 1 a

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

`exit` just kills the kernel that the notebook is relying on for execution.

Interestingly enough however, There seems to be a parameter you can pass to modify that behaviour as well.

Test 2:
Cell 1
`a = 3`
Cell 2
`exit(keep_kernel=True)`
cell 3
`print(a)`
resulted in
`3`

EDIT: And looks like @user2357112's answer fills in the missing pieces.
EDIT2: Actually, it seems to be an instance of [`IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.autocall.html#IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall)

```
 class IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall(ip=None)

    Bases: IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall

    Exit IPython. Autocallable, so it needn’t be explicitly called.
    Parameters: keep_kernel (bool) – If True, leave the kernel alive. Otherwise, tell the kernel to exit too (default).
```

Comment: Ah nice. I was trying to work out what this might do. So it looks like, from your test, it wipes the namespace?

Comment: In Spyder it is restarting the IPython kernel. You already have my upvote, but I think you could do with adding the documentation for this (my lame way of backing out of a fiddly google search :P)

Comment: mhm, i am actually really intrigued by this behaviour, tracking down the documentation atm, however check the edit. @roganjosh It makes me suspect it is doing something not just with namespaces.