# kernel keep dying in jupyter notebook if run any code after exit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

After running this python code in Jupyter Notebook and type o :

```
p = input("type anything for detecting error:")
if p == "hi":
    print(hellow)
else:
    print('hi')
    exit()
print(p)
```

it comes out following:
type anything for detecting error:o
hi
o

Then the kernal dye,and notebook pumps out message:
'The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.'
It should not print o after i exit the program.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1pR9.png)

and even I don't print anything after exit():

```
p = input("type anything for detecting error:")
if p == "hi":
    print(hellow)
else:
    print('hi')
    exit()
p == "hi"
```

it still will pumps out the kernel is dead message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5D2e.png)

so I think I find bug of exit() function in jupyter notebook,right?
Or it just exist in my computer?
Can sb help me figure this out,plz.

Comment: Why do you need `exit()`? Calling it will [actually stop IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53676195/1814420).

Comment: Because I tried to write try and error code  and it did't exit and start print code below it:
```
fname = input('Enter the file name: ')
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print("file doesn't exist!")
    quit()
count = 0
try:
    for line in fhand:
        if line.startswith('Subject:'):
            count = count + 1
except:
    quit()
print('There were', count, 'subject lines in', fname)
```
but if i type " " it just comes out :
Enter the file name: 
file doesn't exist!
There were 0 subject lines in 

so I simplified the code and ask problem below.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes, please consider [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel died not because of your computer, but due to the `exit()` command. As confirmed by a Jupyter Notebook developer [on Github](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1880#issuecomment-260134925):

> At present, using exit() will make the notebook think that the kernel
> has died, and it will automatically start a new kernel.

If you simply want to stop the execution, wrap your code in a function and use `return` instead.

```py
def my_func():
    p = input("type anything for detecting error:")
    if p == "hi":
        print(hellow)
    else:
        print('hi')

        # Use return instead of exit()
        return
    print(p)

# Call the function
my_func()
```

Comment: but Jupiter notebook also do rest of the function after exit(),I wonder why,because if I run it on coursera python code playground, it would not happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually exit Python Program without shutting down the kernel with the help of functions. Your code can be written like this,

```
def main():
    p = input("type anything for detecting error:")
    if p == "hi":
        print(hellow)
    else:
        print('hi')
        return
    print(p)
main()
```

And also the kernel simply dies if you call exit() while sys.exit() raises an error in IPython. This is the only way you can achieve the desired behaviour.