# exit not raising SystemExit in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, exception, jupyter-notebook

I was writing a Python tutorial in Jupyter Notebook and was trying to demonstrate why one should never use a bare `except`.  My example was

```py
try:
    exit(0)
except:
    print('Did not exit')
```

The idea was that `exit` would raise a `SystemExit` which inherits from `BaseException`.  However, the kernel still died when I ran the cell.

Running this code in IPython displays

```
Did not exit
```

What does `exit` do in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \`exit\` keyword do in Python3 with Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676034/what-does-exit-keyword-do-in-python3-with-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: @Ake, I saw that post but it didn't explain what `exit` does under the hood.